# Adding SQS as eventSource to Lambda in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am writing CDK app to deploy aws infra using Python.

CDK generates a cft template that deploy infra inside aws account. Now, I want to configure a SQS generated from CDK to be an event source for the lambda(generated from another stack in the same account). I am giving a name to other stack so that I can reference it inside my CDK function.

```
>   Outputs:
>     StackArn:
>       Description: Use this as the stack_arn in your cloud_formation_deployment_stack
>         override.
>       Value: {Ref: 'AWS::StackId'}
>       Export:
>         Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-DemoExportName"
```

AWS-Stack-DemoExportName - export name of lambda stack

Inside my CDK script(stack.py), I was able to import the lambda -

```
impt_lambda = core.Fn.import_value('AWS-Stack-DemoExportName')
```

impt_lambda is a string here with the lambda identifier which I am not able to use to configure event source for the lambda. How can I use this output to configure event sources and other attributes to my lambda